# Integration by Substitution: substituting variable with complex functions

Tags: integration

I'm learning integration by the method of substitution. While doing sums, I encountered a case in which I got this expression in the denominator: $$\sqrt {a^2 + x^2 } $$

Now, I wanted to substitute  $x$ as $a i \sin \theta$ where $i = \sqrt  {-1} $. My idea was to take $a$ outside the root, and obtain $\cos \theta $ from the root.

Although I've reached the answer, I couldn't find any complex function substitution example in my book, which makes me wonder whether my substitution is correct.

Can I substitute a variable with a complex function in integration?

Comment: $x=ai\sin \theta$ will give $a^2(1+\sin ^2\theta)$. How you are getting $\text{cos}\, \theta$ from there? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @Krish Sorry, that will be a "+". See edit.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163946/are-complex-substitutions-legal-in-integration) might be helpful.